# Checking HTTP Status of Many Pages on IIS Express: Crashes IIS Express

Tags: c#, iis, optimization, iis-express

I am writing a simple C# console application, whose main job is, when given a set of URLs, to ping those URLs and report whether or not an `HTTP 200 OK` result was returned. The real life data set is in the area of 20,000 URLs to test (to verify that an en-masse edit did not ruin any of the pages).

Currently, the code that checks the response looks like this:

```
public UrlTestResult TestUrl(string url)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
    }
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> message = client.GetAsync(url);
            if (message == null || message.Result == null)
            {
                return new FailedUrlTestResult(url, "No response was returned.");
            }
            if (message.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return new SuccessfulUrlTestResult(url);
            }
            return new FailedUrlTestResult(url, "{0}: {1}".Format((int)message.Result.StatusCode, message.Result.ReasonPhrase));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new FailedUrlTestResult(url, "An exception occurred: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This code does work for smaller sets of data. Even if I iterate over the collection of URLs using `Parallel.ForEach` instead of a normal `foreach`, it behaves fine. After running for a few minutes or so, however, when parsing the 20,000 dataset, IIS Express (hosting localhost) will crash.

I'm guessing that my options are:

- Run out of IIS and see if that works
- Throttle the number of requests to give IIS Express a chance to breathe (trick here is how much to throttle)
- Test the URLs in smaller chunks (similar to the second option)

What I am wondering is:

- Is there a "cheaper" way to ping a URL and get its HTTP response back than `HttpClient`?
- Are there any configuration options for IIS or IIS Express that I should be taking into consideration?

EDIT: I'm finding that IIS Express seems to simply be running out of memory. Pictured is the instance where the crash occurs:

[image: IIS Express Out of Memory Exception]

Which means that IIS Express is holding on to memory that it obviously doesn't need to be (because once the request is over, I don't care about it anymore). Don't know if this'll help solve my problem any, though.

Comment: Are you invoking directly `TestUrl` in the *Parallel.ForEach* ? The `HttpClient` class is designed so that an instance can be reused safely. (See the Remarks section here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Thus you should not instantiate an instance of HttpClient per url.

Comment: @Gabi I have updated the code to only use a single `HttpClient` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed to running `localhost` out of IIS instead of IIS Express. The memory usage was about the same, but it never crashed at any point for the ten minutes that the application was running. I also took Gabi's comment/suggestion and made `HttpClient` only be instantiated one time instead of once per test. The final code looks like this:

```
public sealed class UrlTester : IUrlTester
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public UrlTestResult TestUrl(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
        }

        try
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> message = httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            if (message == null || message.Result == null)
            {
                return new FailedUrlTestResult(url, "No response was returned.");
            }
            if (message.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return new SuccessfulUrlTestResult(url);
            }
            return new FailedUrlTestResult(url, "{0}: {1}".FormatCurrentCulture((int)message.Result.StatusCode, message.Result.ReasonPhrase));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new FailedUrlTestResult(url, "An exception occurred: " + ex);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (httpClient != null)
        {
            httpClient.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And the caller to this class utilizes C#'s `using` statement to ensure that the `HttpClient` instance is properly disposed of.